# JAXB com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory Class Not Found in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jboss7.x

While using JAXB in JBoss, I am getting below exception while executing the code:

```
  JAXBContext   jaxbContext   = JAXBContext.newInstance( jaxbElement.getClass().getPackage().getName() );
```

Exception which i am getting is:

```
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from [Module "deployment.project.ear.subproject-jboss.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:156) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:108) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:258) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:279) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.4.Final-redhat-3]
```

It looks like JBoss JAXB module is loading instead of JDK and this is the reason of exception, however I am not sure how to solve this error?

Comment: JBoss's using its own JAXB module perhaps because you're not packing the JAXB jars with your application. How are you packing your application?

Comment: I have jaxrpc.jar in class path and i think it is sufficient. Am i right?

Comment: In your class-path you should have *jaxb-api* and *jaxb-impl* dependencies. How are you packing your application? Are you using any type of building tool, like Maven?

Comment: I am using ant build, as this is very old application and i recently migrated it from oc4j to JBoss. The logic was working fine in OC4J but having issues in JBoss EAP 6.4.2.1

Comment: Then, on your deployment MANIFEST.MF file, add the following dependency: `Dependencies: com.sun.xml.bind services export`.

Comment: I added this line in MANIFEST.MF, however i did not added jaxb jars in class path as they are already available with jdk, so do i need to add jaxb jars as well including the above line?

Comment: No, because, as you correctly said, they're already provided. Just add the [line mentioned above](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/169148?tstart=0).

Comment: After changes I got another error:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"
 ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/QName"

Comment: Jboss's already loading that class from another *jar* file. You're maybe packing a *jar* that contains *javax/xml/namespace/QName* with your application when JBoss already has it in its libs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106689/discussion-between-gaurav-and-aribeiro).

Comment: @aribeiro, i removed jaxrpc.jar which is causing javax/xml/namespace/QName, I am again getting the same error as mentioned in question :(
So actually i am clueless, what I am doing wrong

Comment: I found something "Instead of system do an import on "javax.api". This is an aggregate module that filters everything out which conflicts with javaee packages." in article https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1470, but not understood what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it by changing default context factory to eclipse link context factory, but not sure why it does not worked with default one.

```
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(  clss.getPackage().getName() , clss.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

and by importing `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory` class.