# embed Javax to Java 9

Tags: java, hibernate, java-9

im trying to fix this for hours, I need help:

Its the not unknown problem, that javax is not part of java 9, I cant figure out how to get it run without the following exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in FILE C:\Users\Miles\Workspace\Projekte\SpringProjekte\RestForFun\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlFile(ConfigLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:167)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:300)
at noobz.teamz.RestForFun.RestForFunApplication.main(RestForFunApplication.java:31)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
... 9 more
```

this is my example:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import java.io.*;


public class RestForFunApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        RestForFunApplication rsf = new RestForFunApplication();

        File file = new File("resources\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
        if (!file.exists())
            System.out.println("no hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Configuration sessionFactory = new Configuration();
        sessionFactory.configure(file);
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>noobz.teamz</groupId>
<artifactId>RestForFun</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>RestForFun</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>9</release>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                    <arg>javax.xml.bind</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">usr</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">psswrd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
</session-factory>
```

I added

```
--add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.activation
```

and

```
--add-modules java.se.ee
```

to intellij idea compiler-settings and also tried to run via console with this.

Nothing works, I still get the exception. Im allmost crying, is extremly nessecary to get this work.

Comment: I recommend first trying to get it to work with Maven from the command line. Your pom says _javax.xml.bind_, but the module is called _java.xml.bind_ (no _x_ after _java_). Although that should have let to a different error...

Comment: The exception does look like _java.xml.bind_ is loaded, though. Otherwise the `JAXBException` would not be available - maybe [this Q&A can help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36041656/2525313)?

Comment: Can you replace the dependency on `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.3.0` with a dependency on `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0`, `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0` and `javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0`? I think these are the right coordinates for the JAXB implementation (you have the correct coordinates for the JAXB API). Also you can drop the `--add-modules` from your POM as you are using the standalone version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a good question. But it can be simplified to the very short example, so you don't need to bother readers with `spring` or `hibernate` dependencies. Already this short code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
}
```

will cause the problem (consider `Foo` be any POJO).

In fact the all existent solutions on S.O. which tell about this problem do not work properly (for instance, this "canonical" question: [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)). I don't know wether it is a consequences of some updates on recent Java JDK (9.0.1), or I am cooking it wrongly. However. I personally think that playing with `--add-module` properties is not a clean way. I believe, that proper way would be use only maven dependencies. And I have found this needed minimal list, it is:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So you don't need to explicitly specify `--add-module` anymore, just remove it.

---

P.S. In your particular code please also fix this property:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

as you use Java-9.

Comment: Your right, this changes made a huge effort! Thank you. Now if i changed back my code and started it there is a long debug list ending with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider. Im unable to find the right dependency (shame on me). Do you have a hint? I want have a success before marking as correct. Ty :)

Comment: Have you tried this dependency? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final

Comment: But any way, this issue is out of scope of your initial question. If I have helped you to solve this particular issue, then accepting the answer would be fair

Comment: This dependeny solved it! Please add it to your answer for the next. Thank you! Not only for the answer but also for this clue to find correct dependencies!

Comment: Thanks, after trying multiple other suggestions in other places this worked great for me.  I'd upvote twice if I could!

Answer (score 0):

I've found (and checked) next set of dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See [Upgrade to Java 10 now](https://medium.com/criciumadev/java-10-migration-5d853f5b5f7e)

UPDATE: for Java 11 it's enough:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
    </dependency>
```

See [Migrating to Java 11](https://medium.com/criciumadev/its-time-migrating-to-java-11-5eb3868354f9)